# Including current date in python logging file

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have a process that I run every day.  It uses Python logging.  How would I configure the python logging module to write to a file containing the current date in the file name?

Because I restart the process every morning the TimedRotatingFileHandler won't work.  The project is larger, so I would be interested in keeping the code required for logging into a logging configuration file.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [TimedRotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler). For example:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

LOG_FILENAME = '/tmp/log'

# Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME, when='D')
log.addHandler(handler)
```

But this will probably only work if your program runs for more than one day. If your script starts daily in a cron job you're better off manually formatting the filename which you pass to your log handler to include a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the TimedRotatingFileHandler see http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler